# Why isn't all the attributes of my class being rendered?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a header partial for a Ruby on Rails app and for some reason the attributes I'm passing through to the class of an element isn't going through.  As of right now the partial looks like this

```
<header class="admin-nav-header">
  <%= link_to spree.admin_path, class: 'brand-link' do %>
    <%= logo img_options: {class: 'img-responsive2', width: '170', position: 'absolute', top: '10px'} %>
  <% end %>
</header>
```

The logo is showing up and resized down to the size needed, but it's not positioning where I want it.  No matter what I come up with it stays in the same place.  I tried adding a display attribute of both block and inline, I tried using a position attribute of relative.  I looked at the space in the inspection tool in chrome and there's plenty room in the containing element for it to fit.  Why won't it move to where I need it?

Comment: try this `<%= logo img_options: { class: 'img-responsive2', width: '170', style: "position: absolute; top: 10px;" } %>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue is with `position` and `top` attributes. They are not HTML attribute but a CSS Property. So they need to be passed to `style` attribute.

You could try following code

```
<header class="admin-nav-header">
  <%= link_to spree.admin_path, class: 'brand-link' do %>
    <%= logo img_options: {class: 'img-responsive2', width: '170', style: 'position: absolute; top: 10px;'} %>
  <% end %>
</header>
```

Comment: GREAT THAT WORKED!!!... I thought it already was reading in CSS so I didn't even think to add "style" to it.